# How to change option background color on hover

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, html-select, background-color

I have been trying to change the background color of the option elements of a select dropdown on a mouse hoverover and I can't get it to work in Chrome, the hoverover always displays as blue. It works perfectly fine in Firefox, and :hover works on other elements in Chrome, but I can't get option:hover to change the background color.

Is there some trick to getting Chrome to change the color or is it a limitation of the brower?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsoCE.png)

```
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>



    option:hover {
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
```

I have tried option:hover { background-color: trasnparent !important; }, but it's not working.
I've looked at solutions suggested by other developers for similar problems, but they don't help much.